# Exception calling object as function in AppRegistry.runApplication

Tags: android, react-native

I have some error in my React native android app, especially in startup code.

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import codePush from 'react-native-code-push';
import App from './src/App';
import store from './src/store/store';

const Wrapper = () => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <App />
    </Provider>
);

AppRegistry.registerComponent('myApp', () => Wrapper);
```

I am getting the following red screen error in React native.
[image]

I am pasting the MainApplication.java code - just in case that is helpful.

```
package com.myapp;

import android.app.Application;
import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.BV.LinearGradient.LinearGradientPackage;
import com.RNFetchBlob.RNFetchBlobPackage;
import com.horcrux.svg.SvgPackage;
import com.learnium.RNDeviceInfo.RNDeviceInfo;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.microsoft.codepush.react.CodePush;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;
import com.clevertap.android.sdk.ActivityLifecycleCallback;
import com.clevertap.react.CleverTapPackage;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;


public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

    private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {

        /* protected String getJSBundleFile() {
            return CodePush.getJSBundleFile();
        } */

        @Override
        public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
            return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new RNDeviceInfo(),
                new LinearGradientPackage(),
                new SvgPackage(),
                new RNFetchBlobPackage(),
                new CleverTapPackage()
                // new CodePush("KbxkSGsHBP8juy8-du9vt9QHaJ75r1BshsUMf", getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            );
        }

        @Override
        protected String getJSMainModuleName() {
            return "index.android";
        }
  };

    @Override
    public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
        return mReactNativeHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        ActivityLifecycleCallback.register(this);
        super.onCreate();
        SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
    }

}
```

And the logs are here:

```
--------- beginning of system
--------- beginning of main
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.ctor()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.createReactContextInBackground()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackgroundInner()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.onJSBundleLoadedFromServer()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.recreateReactContextInBackground()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.runCreateReactContextOnNewThread()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.createReactContext()
D/ReactNative( 3029): Initializing React Xplat Bridge.
D/ReactNative( 3029): Initializing React Xplat Bridge before initializeBridge
D/ReactNative( 3029): Initializing React Xplat Bridge after initializeBridge
D/ReactNative( 3029): CatalystInstanceImpl.runJSBundle()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext()
D/ReactNative( 3029): CatalystInstanceImpl.initialize()
D/ReactNative( 3029): ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance()
I/ReactNativeJS( 3029): [CodePush] The CodePush module doesn't appear to be properly installed. Please double-check that everything is setup correctly.
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Warning: Native component for "RCTView" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Warning: Native component for "RCTImageView" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Warning: Native component for "RCTTextInlineImage" does not exist
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Warning: Native component for "RCTPdf" does not exist
I/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Running application "kalhattiApp" with appParams: {"rootTag":1}. __DEV__ === true, development-level warning are ON, performance optimizations are OFF
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Warning: Failed prop type: Maximum call stack size exceeded.
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in View (at UnimplementedView.js:33)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in UnimplementedView (at View.js:113)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in View (at UnimplementedView.js:33)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in UnimplementedView (at View.js:113)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in View (at UnimplementedView.js:33)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in UnimplementedView (at View.js:113)
...
...
[deleted similar lines]
...
...
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in View (at UnimplementedView.js:33)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in UnimplementedView (at View.js:113)
W/ReactNativeJS( 3029):     in View (at
E/ReactNativeJS( 3029): Maximum call stack size exceeded.
```

Comment: This is a common error- you should close all react-native cli terminals, delete all "builds" folder and then restart it... Sometimes it may be because of diff version of `ReactNative` so try again `npm install react-native`. It should work now.

Comment: @BeingExpert That did not work!

Comment: can you please paste your App and store js files here ?

Comment: @OsmanGoniNahid There is no problem with App or store because the same startup code works fine on iOS. It must be something else!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed adding MainReactPackage in the list of packages!

I probably overlooked it or deleted it by mistake.